# C++, namespaces, name lookup on inherited class and Qt

Tags: c++, c++11, qt

I have built Qt5 with the QT_NAMESPACE=Qt_ns option.

The following code compiles OK. But why?

```
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

namespace test_ns
{
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~MainWindow();

private:
  Qt_ns::Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};    
}
```

QMainWindow is wrapped in the namespace Qt_ns so I would have thought it necessary to prefix this name with Qt_ns as in

```
class MainWindow : public Qt_ns::QMainWindow
```

I have googled in vain, reading the C++ standard to no avail.
I do not think ADL is applicable here as it applies to function, err, arguments.
I have searched the Qt sources on QMainWindow but I got lost in that too.

So, over to you and extend my knowledge please.

Answer (score 2):

Check `qglobal.h` you'll see a `QT_USE_NAMESPACE` when `QT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE` is not defined. with the following comment:

```
# ifndef QT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE
   /*
    This expands to a "using QT_NAMESPACE" also in _header files_.
    It is the only way the feature can be used without too much
    pain, but if people _really_ do not want it they can add
    DEFINES += QT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE to their .pro files.
    */
   QT_USE_NAMESPACE
# endif
```

this allows using `QMainWindow` directly without using the namespaces

Comment: I actually beat you to this. I did a search on the Qt source for QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE and looked at all the namespace stuff.